# How to print column in python array?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have an array of 3 numbers per row, 4 columns deep.
I am struggling to figure out how I can write the code to print all numbers from a specified column rather than from a row.

I have searched for tutorials that explain this easily and just cannot find any that have helped.
Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip

Comment: can you post an example array?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you're thinking of python lists as rows and columns, probably better to use numpy arrays (if you're not already). Then you can print the various rows and columns easily, E.g.

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[1,2,6],[4,5,8],[8,3,5],[6,5,4]])
#Print first column
print(a[:,0])
#Print second row
print(a[1,:])
```

Note that otherwise you have a list of lists and you'd need to use something like,

```
b = [[1,2,6],[4,5,8],[8,3,5],[6,5,4]]
print([i[0] for i in b])
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do this:

```
>>> a = [[1,2,3],[1,1,1],[2,1,1],[4,1,2]]
>>> print [row[0] for row in a]
[1, 1, 2, 4]
```